# Find and rename unhide files to dot files (hide files)

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writting my dotfiles and i want to want to find unhide files in arborescence structure, after make a symbolic link into my home directory.

```
for f in `find ../dotfiles -mindepth 2 -type f`; do ln -sfn "${f}" ".${f}"; done
```

but this code failed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfmAS.png)

Comment: Can you provide an example of sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Look closer at your error log, `find` complains about paths like `.../dotfiles/rest/of/the/path`, where the three leading dots are the result of the expansion of `.${f}`. Since you said you wanted copies in your home directory, the desired expansion would be `~/.path` (or maybe `./.path` would work too, assuming you're executing `find` from your home directory).

A solution to that problem would be to use `basename` to strip the leading directories from the full file path :

```
for f in `find ../dotfiles -mindepth 2 -type f`; do
    filename="$(basename "$f")"
    ln -sfn "${f}" "~/.$filename"
done
```

However the way you iterate over the output of `find` is prone to breaking over IFS : if one of the matched files contains a space for instance, it will be iterated over as two distinct elements. We might as well fix that too :

```
find ../dotfiles -mindepth 2 -type f -print0 | while IFS='' read -r -d $'\0' f; do
    filename="$(basename "$f")"
    ln -sfn "${f}" "~/.$filename"
done
```

In this code, we use `find`'s `-print0` action to delimit its results with the ASCII NUL `\0`, which can't be found in filenames. Then we iterate over the output of `find` with a `while/read` loop that uses that same delimiter. This way we're guaranteed to never choke because of an unexpected character in any filename.